# inline-command to move all files, directories and sub-directories

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am trying to create a batch file that should move files AND directories + all subdirectories from one place into another

For example, let's say I have these:

```
C:\Source\abc.files  
C:\Source\Dir1\abc2.files  
C:\Source\Dir1\Sub1\abc3.files  
C:\Source\Dir2\xyz.files
```

When I use `move C:\Source\*.* C:\Dest\` ONLY `abc.files` show up on the destination folder. I need the whole content of `Source` directory with ALL its subdirectories contents

3rd party solutions (besides DOS) are OK... if they are free and virus free. =)

Comment: DOS is a distinct OS. If you're running any version of Windows more recent than Windows ME then you're not using DOS.

Comment: If you notice carefully, I am making a batch file (ej. `automation.bat`) with several inline-commands (DOS ATM). Regardless of the windows version, anyone can do that and use DOS

Comment: No, you're using command line tools, not DOS.

Comment: You're writing a batch. That said, why not just move `Source`? Also your current filter is looking for objects with a dot. `Dir1` etc. don't have that. So just use `*` instead and try again instead of `*.*`.

Comment: Assuming you are using Windows 7+, how about `XCOPY /E /I /Y "Source" "Destination"` ([XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)) or perhaps (preferably) [Robocopy](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You're running into two problems here.

The first is that you told `move` to only copy files that have a name that matches the `*.*` pattern. `Dir1` and `Dir2` both do not match `*.*`. (Neither has a "`.`" (dot) in the name). @Seth pointed this out in a comment on your original post.

The second problem is that `move` doesn't have sane (imho) behavior when you ask it to move a folder and a file at the same time. Move simply refuses to move a folder if anything else is trying to be moved at the same time:

Moves a dir into another dir:

```
move C:\Source\Dir1 C:\Dest\
```

(now `C:\Dest\Dir1` exists)

Only moves files at the top level inside `C:\Source\`:

```
move C:\Source\* C:\Dest\
```

(now `C:\Dest\abc.files` exists)

Produces a syntax error when you try to move two folders at once (neither syntax works for me)

```
move C:\Source\Dir1,C:\Source\Dir2 C:\Dest\
move C:\Source\Dir1 C:\Source\Dir2 C:\Dest\
```

The documentation for `move` suggests that you should be able to specify multiple files and folders to move at once with a comma (`,`) separating the files to be moved but this doesn't seem to work for me.

The documentation does say `Moves files and renames files and directories.` suggesting that it really can't move directories...

So, I don't think there is a solution that works for you with the `move` command that is available on DOS compatible machines. There are however other newer commands available in more recent versions of Windows that would likely work. `xcopy` is a popular one. This unfortunately doesn't work for me because `xcopy` does not do a filesystem level move, it only copies and then deletes the original. This is fine for smaller files but can be disastrous with larger files.